# juju bootstrap unrecognized args

Tags: server, juju

I am trying to setup juju on my ubuntu server.  I did a fresh install two days ago and installed juju as per https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started.

I configured lxd to use an existing bridge, rather than using lxd-bridge.  Lxd works fine and I have two lxd containers running sucessfully.  However, when I try to run `juju bootstrap lxd-test localhost`, I get `error: unrecognized args: ["lxd-test" "localhost"]`.  I also tried `juju bootstrap lxd-xenial lxd` and got `error: unrecognized args: ["lxd-xenial" "lxd"]`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're on either 14.04 (Trusty) or have managed to install Juju 1.25. The stable documentation is geared towards Juju 2.0 which is available in Xenial or by adding `ppa:juju/devel`. Once you have the latest version of Juju 2.0 installed you should be able to proceed with the instructions!